# Android- How to use Spinner in an AlertDialog?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a spinner, how can i bind it to an AlertDialog? It is possible to do that?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

please try this :

```
 public class WvActivity extends Activity {

TextView tx;
String[] s = { "India ", "Arica", "India ", "Arica", "India ", "Arica",
        "India ", "Arica", "India ", "Arica" };
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(WvActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, s);

    tx= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt1);
    final Spinner sp = new Spinner(WvActivity.this);
    sp.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    sp.setAdapter(adp);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(WvActivity.this);
    builder.setView(sp);
    builder.create().show();
  }
 }
```

Comment: can I ask you a question: where is the LayoutParams.Wrap_content from? I mean which package should I import

Comment: import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;

Comment: Thanks, I got it. In fact, how can I get the chosen result in this spinner after I clicked to one row? What method should I use? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead why don't you use an activity and set it to Dialog style. Should be like the same visual approach and you can design your dialog just as you want it.

Answer (score 0):

public void CreateAlertDialog1() {

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View alertLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.note_dialog, null);
    final EditText etName = (EditText) alertLayout.findViewById(R.id.enter_name);
    final TextView call_date = alertLayout.findViewById(R.id.call_date);
    call_date.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    date_time_display = alertLayout.findViewById(R.id.date_time_display);
     date_time_select = alertLayout.findViewById(R.id.date_time_select);
    final Spinner spSex = (Spinner) alertLayout.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    String[] status_note = new String[] {
            "Laceflower",
            "Sugar maple",
            "Mountain mahogany",
            "Butterfly weed"
    };

    final List<String> plantsList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(status_note));

    // Initializing an ArrayAdapter
    @SuppressLint({"NewApi", "LocalSuppress"}) final ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()),R.layout.spinner_item,plantsList);

    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item);
    spSex.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);



    date_time_select.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
                newFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");

        }
    });

    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    alert.setTitle(client_name_display);
    alert.setIcon(getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.addnote));
    alert.setView(alertLayout);
    alert.setCancelable(false);
    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "Cancel clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            OkHttpHandler okHttpHandler = new OkHttpHandler(status, res, start_date_time, end_date_time, etName.getText().toString());
            okHttpHandler.execute("https://management.reflectdm.com/api/call-management");

        }
    });

    alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            String user = etName.getText().toString();
            String sex = String.valueOf(spSex.getSelectedItem());
            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Name: " + user + "\nBirthday: " + bday + "\nSex: " + sex + "\nHungry: " + hungry, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            OkHttpHandler okHttpHandler = new OkHttpHandler(status, res, start_date_time, end_date_time, etName.getText().toString());
            okHttpHandler.execute("https://management.reflectdm.com/api/call-management");


        }
    });
    AlertDialog dialog = alert.create();
    dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! As a courtesy, it is required that whenever you post an answer, you give an explanation. Also, should you post code snippets, kindly clean them with proper documentation.